# Client server protocol in Android

Tags: android

I am designing an application on Android which is based on client/server structure.
I want to work with Interface object which are shared between the client and the server such like RMI, or web service
For example the client calls `createCustomer(Icustomer Data)`
And the server implement this method.

It’s very important for me to make serialization of the interfaces over the network.
What is the common and the efficient way to do this Android?

Answer (score 1):

JSON, as implemented in the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) or as implemented by [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), or [xml](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/package-summary.html).

Comment: Can I serialize interface between client and server with JSON

Comment: Yes gson supports serialization and deserialization of custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I have done for client/server model is with JAX-WS(in my example my server was a glassfish server with exposed SOAP webservice methods. [Glassfish JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/glassfish/GFandMySQL_Part3.html))

I then consumed the XML SOAP messages on the client(android app) using ksoap2-android libraries([ksoap2-android webpage](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)) since they are lighter weight than the clunky JAXB libraries(However, the JAXB would be easier to work with).

If you want to go with this approach I can share with you some code samples, and how I made KSoap2 easier to work with.

Keep in mind JSON in terms of efficiency is more efficient than SOAP because of the overheads associated with SOAP.